# Am I damaging my Induction cooker by putting piece of metal under aluminium pan?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I have bought induction cooker and to use my old cooking pan I have placed a sheet of metal and it seems to work ok...

[However it is making hissing noise](https://youtu.be/h6tw_inxsS4)... am I damaging my induction cooker by doing this...

**Am I damaging my Induction cooker by putting piece of metal under aluminium pan?**

P.S I will get a proper metal pan this is just a temporary solution...

Comment: Madness, I would have never done experiments like that with induction cooker! U may be damaging it, and the effects you will perhaps see with time.

Comment: @WrichikBasu In what way exactly i am damaging it?

Comment: I would expect the metal to melt.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie How come? Workings of induction cooker is like magic to us mere mortals...

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius - Perhaps rephrase the question a little to make less open-ended and more focused.  For instance, try just asking about reasons why placing a metal sheet over an inducting cooker could cause damage to sheet and/or inductors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With induction cooking, the cooktop is safer because it does not need to heat up the food, the pot does that by means of the magnetic field induced in it.

I don't  believe you are damaging the the cooking top, because it merely produces a magnet field, under a sheet of hardened glass. Although you don't  say what the piece of metal is, I am guessing you are using a sheet of ferrous metal on top of which sits an aluminium pan or pot.

This is the same layout that manufactured aluminium pots use, a ferrous metal base is securely bonded to the bottom of the aluminium pot, as ferrous metals are more efficient at transferring the magnetic energy from the cooker into the heat energy needed to cook the food.

Obviously, the hissing sound could be trapped water,  but equally obviously, the sooner you get proper cookware, the better, to eliminate the spaces between the bottom of the aluminium pot and the sheet of metal.  This ad hoc arrangement, while it is something I might try myself, is potentially dangerous if you trap a lot of water under the pot.

From [Induction cooker noises](http://products.geappliances.com/appliance/gea-support-search-content?contentId=18149)

> A Humming sound while cooking or boiling is normal. Slight sounds, like hums or buzzes may be produced by different types of cookware. Heavier pans, such as enameled cast iron produce less noise than a lighter weight multi-ply stainless steel pan. The size of the pan and the amount of contents can also contribute to the sound level.
>
> When using adjacent elements that are set at certain power level settings, pan noise may interact and produce a low whistle or intermittent "hum". These noises can be reduced or eliminated by lowering or raising the power level settings of one or both of the elements. Pans that completely cover the element ring will produce less noise.

I  appreciate you say hissing, not humming, but your setup is not exactly the same as the above. Could a buzz be interpreted as a hiss?

Comment: Hissing sound isn't water...

Comment: Check the video you are welcome to decide if it is hiss, buzz or humm, lol. https://youtu.be/h6tw_inxsS4

Comment: I did, it's a hiss/buzz kind of sound :)